# SQL query issue (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are:

`Customers`:

```
Phone  |  City
-------------------
1234   |  Chicago
2345   |  New York
1234   |  Toronto
```

`City`:

```
City      |  Country
--------------------
Chicago   |  USA
New York  |  USA
Las Vegas |  USA
Toronto   |  Canada
Montreal  |  Canada
```

User query: Phone = `1234`, City = `New York`

If a phone number (`1234`) is searched in a city (`New York`). Even though there is no phone number (`1234`) that exists in the searched city (`New York`), But if that phone number (`1234`) exists in any city (`Chicago`) of the same country (`USA`) as of the searched city (`New York`), I want to fetch the details from `Customers` table because that phone number (`1234`) exists in any other city (`Chicago`) of the country (`USA`) which is the same country of the searched city (`New York`).

So, if user searches for phone = `1234`, city = `New York`:

Result: Phone = `1234`, city = `Chicago`

Unfortunately, user can not enter `country` name. He can only input `phone` and `city`

Update: Sorry, I forgot to mention that city name is primary key in City table. I purposely did it for the sake of simplicity. If there are 2 cities in 2 countries with same name, I only added the bigger one and did not add smaller one.

Comment: As I understand the question: You have to take customers from the customer's table with search term phone number and city regardless of countries associated it.
Why don't you query the tables with join queries without using the search term city.
Example: 

    select city.city,phone from customers join city on city.city=customers.city where phone= 1234;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Phone = 1234 AND City IN (SELECT City FROM city WHERE Country = (SELECT Country FROM city WHERE City = 'New York'));
```

Just replace the Phone and City in the query with the ones you want to search for.

Comment: `.. WHERE Country = (SELECT Country ..` There are cities with the same name, but in different countries. If so then the query will fail.

Comment: Oh yes you are correct, just tested it with the given data :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that city name is primary key in City table.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that city name is primary key in City table. I purposely did it for the sake of simplicity. If there are 2 cities in 2 countries with same name, I only added the bigger one and did not add smaller one.

Answer (score 5):

Test this:

```
SELECT t1.Phone, t2.City /* , t2.Country */
FROM Customers t1
JOIN City t2 USING (City)
JOIN City t3 USING (Country)
WHERE t1.Phone = 1234
  AND t3.City = 'New York'
```

Of course the query may produce more than one row. You may add `ORDER BY t2.City = 'New York' DESC` for the row with specified city to be the most upper (if exists).

Comment: If there's New York in another country it will also be returned in the query. There's not really a way without adding the country filter to the query to make it bulletproof that only customers from given country are returned.

Comment: @drodil *If there's New York in another country it will also be returned in the query* Not only specified city (New York) but also the customer city (Chicago) must exist in this another country for to be returned. But in this case there is no way for to distinguish what country the user needs in. This is why all found rows must be returned. Country output added (as a comment) for this purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that city name is primary key in City table.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that city name is primary key in City table. I purposely did it for the sake of simplicity. If there are 2 cities in 2 countries with same name, I only added the bigger one and did not add smaller one.

Comment: @ComputerUser *I forgot to mention that city name is primary key in City table.* This is the reason why I recommend to provide complete CREATE TABLE for each table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query

```
SELECT phone, city
FROM Customers
WHERE phone = 1234   
    AND city IN 
    (
        SELECT city 
        FROM City
        WHERE country IN 
            (
                SELECT country 
                FROM city
                WHERE city = 'New York'
            )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but here's another solution. This creates a *rank* of matches and picks off the highest ranked match; you could easily adapt this to return additional matches based on matchability or similar criteria etc

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0546a0a7f596154893bc244992e53307)

```
select c.phone, c.city
from customers c
where c.phone='1234'
order by 
case when exists (
        select * from cities ct where ct.city='new york'
            and ct.country=(select country from cities x where x.city=c.city)
        )
    then 1 else 0 end desc
limit 1
```